# Взаимодействие объектов экземляров класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код,который описывает точку на плоскости по ее координатам, отображает количество экземпляров и сами точки.

```py
class Point_6():
    """ Класс для точек на плоскости"""
    @property
    def coords(self):
        return self.__coord

    @ coords.setter
    def coords(self, value):
        if value < -100:
            self.__coord = 0
        elif value > 100:
            self.__coord = 0
        else:
            self.__coord = value

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        Point_6.count += 1

    def __del__(self):
        Point_6.count -= 1
        print("Object destroyed!")

    count = 0

    @staticmethod
    def display_count():  # Отображение количества точек
        print(f"Point count = {Point_6.count}")

    def display_point(self):  # Отображение точки
        print(f"Point({self.x}, {self.y})")

    def change_coords(self, offset_x, offset_y):
        self.x += offset_x  # Смещение х на offset_x
        self.y += offset_y  # Смещение y на offset_y


# Work with object
point_list = [Point_6(10, -2),
              Point_6(0, -7),
              Point_6(-4, 4),
              Point_6(-1, 5)]
```

по условию задачи нужно расчитать расстояние между второй и четвертой точкой,заданных в списке. Я знаю что расстояние находится по формуле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Но как реализовать это программно?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас же в экземплярах класса есть члены `.x`, `.y`

что вам запрещает сделать так:

```
def distance(point1, point2):
    return ((point1.x - point2.x)**2 + (point1.y - point2.y)**2)**0.5

res = distance(point_list[0], point_list[2])
```

ну или в сам класс запихнуть данную функцию как метод и вызывать например так:

```
def distance(self, point):
    return ((self.x - point.x)**2 + (self.y - point.y)**2)**0.5


res = point_list[0].distance(point_list[2])
```